# SteamVR_TrackedObjects disabled on dashboard

Tags: unity, steam, htc-vive, steam-vr

our game relies heavily on some Joints attached (not childs) to the tracked controllers. But those controllers get disabled when a user clicks on the system button which actually break our physics when user get back in game.

Is there a way to keep them active ? i checked they get Disabled in SteamVR_ControllerManager and could just risk commenting that block.

Or any event method called when the user opens the VR Dashboard ?

Thank you.

We are using Unity 5.6.0 and the latest SteamVR plugin.

Comment: Can you detect when they're disabled and just disable your springs at the same time? Then re-enable after that?

Comment: Yes, the onDisable event was fired. the used workaround was  to child the joints to the SteamVR rig anchor, and separate them on OnEnable.

Comment: Cool, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first tried commenting those two methods that appear in [SteamVR_ControllerManager.cs](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steamvr_unity_plugin/blob/master/Assets/SteamVR/Scripts/SteamVR_ControllerManager.cs) line 130

```
// Reparents to a new object and deactivates that object (this allows
// us to call SetActive in OnDeviceConnected independently.
private void HideObject(Transform t, string name)
{
    if (t.gameObject.name.StartsWith(hiddenPrefix))
    {
        Debug.Log("Ignoring double-hide.");
        return;
    }
    var hidden = new GameObject(name).transform;
    hidden.parent = t.parent;
    t.parent = hidden;
    hidden.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
private void ShowObject(Transform t, string name)
{
    var hidden = t.parent;
    if (hidden.gameObject.name != name)
        return;
    t.parent = hidden.parent;
    Destroy(hidden.gameObject);
}
```

Even if it didn't break anything in our Q&A and testings. we kept them as is but instead attached a script on our SteamVR Rig anchors that attach those Joints during the OnDisable() and detach them on OnEnable().